Implementation of Static Flat Map
How to implement a flat map using arrays when keys are known at compile time. Imagine I know my keys:
enum class Asset
{
    FONT,
    TEXTURE
};

struct AssetContainer
{
};

Hence I could do:
struct STATIC_DATA
{
   inline static std::unordered_map<Asset, std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<const AssetContainer>>> ASSET_CACHE = { 
      {Asset::FONT,    nullptr},
      {Asset::TEXTURE, nullptr}
   };

it looks like since I know my keys and size I can optimize this by writing a const size map using arrays as:
template<class Key, class Value, size_t Size>
struct static_map
{
    using container = std::array<std::pair<Key, Value>, Size>;
}


Will this add any gain in terms of speed accessing values knowing that the max size < 50?
Is this implemented somewhere in the standard?
If not 2 how can I implement this in a simple and optimized way? Should I have keys and values as arrays, or 2 arrays containers? I think first one is cache friendly but do I gain anything for size < 50.
How can I implement initializer lists constructor without supplying size so I can do:

struct STATIC_DATA
{
   inline static static_map<Asset, std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<const AssetContainer>>> ASSET_CACHE = { 
      {Asset::FONT,    nullptr},
      {Asset::TEXTURE, nullptr}
   };
};


Note that the Size here really needs to be the maximum potential indexes (the number of values in your enum class) rather than the number of elements in the map.  You can't get that from the initializer list.

Found this https://github.com/DanielDubi/StaticFlatMap/blob/master/include/FlatMap/StaticFlatMap.hpp but not sure how good is it

The compiler will not optimize an unordered map into an array.
template<class Enum, class Value, std::size_t Count>
struct EnumMap:std::array<Value,Count> {
  // Get the array out (base class):
  constexpr std::array<Value, Count>& Array() { return *this; }
  constexpr std::array<Value, Count> const& Array() const { return *this; }

  // lookup in base (array):
  constexpr Value& operator[]( Enum e ) {
    return Array()[ static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(e) ];
  }
  // use non-const version and cast back to const:
  constexpr Value const& operator[]( Enum e ) const {
    return const_cast<Value const&>( const_cast<EnumMap&>(*this)[e] );
  }

  // Build from key-value pairs:
  constexpr EnumMap( std::initializer_list<std::pair<Enum const, Value const>> il ) {
    for (auto const&(key, value):il)
      (*this)[key] = value;
  }
};

that should do it reasonably well.  It does needlessly default construct the values.
EnumMap<Asset, std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<const AssetContainer>>, 2> foo = {
  {Asset::FONT,    nullptr},
  {Asset::TEXTURE, nullptr}
};


should be std::array<Value, Count>. Thanks
